# Концепция создания бота в многопользовательской игре

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, node.js, разработка-игр, gameserver

Предположим есть браузеры в виде клиентов и есть сервер. И общаются они между собой с помощью WebSocket.

Как правило, простой вариант координации в таком варианте, выглядит в виде пачки ифов и с стороны клиента, и с стороны сервера. 
Пример клиента:

```
ws = new WebSocket("wss://site.com:8888/"); 
ws.onopen = function() {
   ws.send({'e':"new", 'x':lPlayer.getX(), 'y':lPlayer.getY()});
};
ws.onmessage = function(event){
   var msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
   if(msg.e == 'new'){
       var newPlayer = new Player(scene, {x,y,z}, msg.x, msg.y);
       newPlayer.id = msg.id;
       newPlayer.init(msg.id);
       remotePlayers.push(newPlayer);    
  }else if(msg.e == 'move' ){
       var movePlayer = playerById(msg.id);
       movePlayer.set(msg.x, msg.y, msg.z);
  }else if(msg.e == 'rotate' ){
      var rotPlayer = playerById(msg.id);
      rotPlayer.setA(msg.a);
      rotPlayer.setB(msg.b);
  } 
}
```

Пример сервера:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8888});
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    clients[max_id] = ws;
    this.id = max_id;
    ws.on('message', function(e) {
       if(e.e == 'new'){
            var p = new Player(max_id, e.x, e.y);
            this.player = p;
            clients.send_all({'e':"new", 'id':p.id, 'x':p.x(), 'y':p.y,'z':p.z});
           players.push(p);
      }else if (e.e == 'move') {
                var p = this.player;
                p.set(e.x, e.y, e.z);
                clients.send_all({'e':"move", 'id':p.id, 'x':p.getX(), 'y':p.getY(), 'z':p.getZ(), 'msg':'move'})
            }
```

Ну и во всем этом самый важный нюанс в том что какая либо активность игрока исходит всегда от клиента, от которого сокетами посылается сообщение серверу, а потом уже сервером транслируется всем остальным игрокам для координации.

А активность бота всегда должен продуцировать сервер и транслировать всем остальным. И вот на этом как раз основная дилема. Пока что приходит в голову идея что нужно прописать в каждую активность игроков то есть на каждый `if (e.e == 'move')` или на каждый `if (e.e == 'shot')` какое то действие бота.

Это наверно может выглядеть как то так:

```
  }else if (e.e == 'move') {
            var p = this.player;
            p.set(e.x, e.y, e.z);
            clients.send_all({'e':"move", 'id':p.id, 'x':p.x, 'y':p.y, 'z':p.z})

            var bot = this.player.bot;
            clients.send_all({'e':"move", 'id':bot.id, 'x':bot.x, 'y':bot.y, 'z':bot.z})

  }
```

Но дальше на этом фантазия заканчивается. Вопрос в том как лучше организовать перемещения бота и в архитектуре игры?

Возможно уже есть на других языках похожие библиотеки на `Python` или на `PHP` любом другом.

Comment: А может не перегружать код сервера еще и действиями бота. Может сделать бота отдельно в виде клиента, который коннектится к серверу почти как обычный пользователь.

Comment: В принцепе тоже вариант, но я не совсем представляю как это реализовать. Потому что клиенты вроде как с браузера конектятся 1 браузер 1 клиент. А бот откуда возьмется?

Comment: Ну нам же нужен совершенно нестандартный клиент, потому как ему не надо делать то, что делают остальные - т.е. отображать в браузере произошедшее в игре. Т.е. его можно написать на любом языке. Желательно что бы для этого языка была клиентская библиотека для WebSocket, хотя как я понимаю протокол там не сложный, реализовать не долго

Comment: Ну и все же я не совсем понимаю как его реализовать в таком случае? Это должен быть еще один процесс запущенный на сервере и эмитирующий браузер?

Или это должен делать браузер первого подключившегося клиента?

Comment: да, процесс на сервере. эмуляцией браузера это можно назвать с большой натяжкой. браузер обычно делает много того, что боту совершенно не нужно. Да, он должен отвечать серверу по тому же протоколу, по которому работает обычный клиент. Ну и посылать запросы для выполнения своих действий как игрока

Comment: Ну выглядит не так очевидно, и все таки хочется реализовать все в рамках одной платформы.

Comment: Кстати, только обратил внимание на `if (e.e == 'move') {
 var p = this.player;
...
 var bot = new Bot(e.x+2, e.y+2, e.z+2);
`. Это создание нового бота на каждое движение пользователя ... много их разведется :) В любом случае жизнь бота должна быть сама по себе, т.е. он не обязан реагировать на любое событие от пользователей, он просто должен как то учесть в своей логике. А действовать он может и самостоятельно, например по таймеру

Comment: Ну это просто общий пример, на самом деле там есть класс, и он в памяти держит всех игроков кто зашёл и бота по их id. Класс общий для всех, и на каждую активность мы получаем из класса по `id` бота и отправляем клиенту новые координаты движения бота. или что он там сделал.

Но такая реализация бота мне кажется довольно не правильной.

Comment: ну тогда бот - отдельный класс. у него есть свой обработчик входящих событий. обработчик входящих событий сервера в самом своем начале (например) вызывает событие в боте отдавая ему то же сообщение. в каждом `if(e.e)` это точно делать не стоит. бот сам решает, что ему делать с этим событием: игнорировать, что то изменить в своем состоянии, совершить действие.

Comment: Ну отдельный класс ладно, а как у него может быть свой обработчик?

Comment: При создании вебсокета на клиенте указывается адрес на котором слушает сервер, адрес может быть любой.

Но сервер должен слушать только этот адрес. И у адреса есть только один роут или только один обработчик. Который по протоколу в свою очередь проверяет открыто или закрыто соединение и собственно занимается передачей данных.

Comment: `var BOT = new Bot;`
А это код твоего существующего серверного обработчика:
`wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
 clients[max_id] = ws;
 this.id = max_id;`
 ...
 BOT.message(e,this);`
Т.е. ты хотел вызывать в каждом if, а я предлагаю делать это там же, но только в 1 месте, что бы код сервера не раздувать.

Comment: Да, и самое главное, почему я хотел отдельный процесс. что бы разработка бота не мешала работе сервера. Но, учитывая, что это node.js ... Главное из кода серверного класса вызывать обработчики бота в `try {}`. И иметь возможность по команде извне перегрузить код бота. Не будешь же ты перезапускать сервак ради правок в боте

Comment: >>> перезапускать сервак ради правок в боте.
буду почему нет :) там же не каждые пол дня новые правки выходят.

>>> но только в 1 месте.
Ну получается что это как раз и основной вопрос как это сделать в одном месте, но чтоб при этом желательно не запускать каких других серверов и тд. Ну и не усложнять особо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: А если не дан исчерпывющий ответ?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше было бы, если бы ядро вашего приложения/игры не зависело так от вида транспорта

```
/** Объект вашей игры */
var Game = {
    /** ф-ция принимает команду и данные, а потом уже выполняет ее */
    command: function (cmd, data, id) {
        /** здесь уже можно делать что угодно, как с командой, так и с данными */
    }
}
```

Схема получается такой

- Игрок совершил действие
- По websocket-ам данные передали на сервер
- Сервер передал данные движку/ядру игре
- Игра обработала данные, сделала необходимые обновления
- Игра возвращает новое состояние себя серверу
- Сервер отправляет всем обновленное состояние

Отсюда получается, что сервер - это лишь посредник между игрой и клиентом.

В примере это выглядит так:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8888});
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    clients[max_id] = ws;
    this.id = max_id;
    ws.on('message', function(e) {
        var cmd = e.e;
        Game.command(cmd, e, this.id);
    }
}

/**
*   @param {string} cmd - команда, которую отослал клиент
*   @param {Object} data - данные команды
*   @param {number} id - id клиента, который послал команду
*/
Game.command = function (cmd, data, id) {
    /** 
    *   тут вся логика игры, команд и так далее
    */

    // результат выполнения отправляйте всем клиентам
    return cmdResult; 
}
```

**Как это поможет с ботом?**

Просто дайте ему возможно напрямую отправлять команды в игру, ведь у нас уже есть ф-ция `Game.command`, которую можно использовать. Cоздавайте экземпляр бота, и либо передавайте ссылку на игру, либо пусть у бота игра уже будет в области видимости. Можно даже создать отдельный интерфейс для бота, который в конце все равно переходит в `Game.command`.

При выполнении команды **ботом**, сообщайте серверу, что нужно разослать данные, можно добавть к объекту `ws` фу-нкции или кастомное событие, которое будет за это отвечать. Придется правда переписать логику игры, ведь теперь игроки будут храниться в объекте `Game`, зато у вас не будет проблем в дальнейшем, так как вы отделили транспортный модуль от игрового.

Answer (score 0):

Мне тоже кажется что бот должен быть отдельным клиентом. Не браузер, а просто клиент к которому сервер будет относится так же, как к любому другому клиенту. То есть сервер вообще не будет знать, кто это, бот или нет

```
//some_bot.js
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/path');
var botsLogic = {
  CRAZY: crazyBot
}

function botInit(x, y, z, type){
  return botsLogic[type](z, y, z);
}

function crazyBot(x, y, z) {
  ws.onopen = function() {
    ws.send({'e':"new", 'x':x, 'y':y, 'z': z});
  };

//do some actions
}
```

Вопрос кто будет инициализировать бота? Нужна какая то фабрика или дип. Тупой пример:

```
function startGame(){
 var newServer = new Server();
 newServer.start();
 require("bot-init").initBot(1, 2, 3, "CRAZY")
}
```

И еще, старайся не писать такое количество ифов. Потому что каждое новое дейстиве пораждает новый иф. Это плохой код. Почитай про паттерн проектирования Стратегия, мне кажется этот паттерн хорошо подойдет для такого случая.)

Comment: Ну ифы приведины как пример для простоты, чтоб не объяснять долго что я хочу.  Я просто не совсем понимаю как его сделать отдельным клиентом?

Если он клиент то его нужно либо запускать как еще один процесс, клиентский процесс так сказать, либо нужно вставить как то код клиента в клиентскую часть игры и получится что допустим браузер одного из реальных игроков будет исполнять код бота а всем остальным будет транслироватся для синхронизации то что делает бот у одного из игроков что вообщем то не совсем правильно.

Comment: А почему тебе собственно не нравится отдельный процесс. Серверный процесс же запускается как то. Вот как нибудь по аналогии стартовать второй процесс. Тут даже написали как он для работы как клиент WebSocks работать будет. Такое ощущение, как будто запуск процесса какая то проблема. гугл по запросу `node.js запуск скрипта` выдает сходу кучу способов.

Comment: Ну во первых потому что я не для себя делаю и хочется чтоб все работало уже из коробки. Запустил серверный скрипт и все.   И во вторых сейчас уж все так сделано что вся информация хранится в памяти. Например все заходящие игроки разбиваются по комнатам, в каждой комнате инициализируется бот. Все это акуратненько хранится в джейсоне. А если сейчас будет отдельный процесс который скорее всего ничего не знает комнатах, игроках и тд. то тогда получится что все надо заново переписывать и кучу всего дублировать.

Comment: Нет, имхо, логика бота должна исполняться на сервере. По крайней мере ради безопасности. 

Я пытался показать в коде, но видимо не особо ясно. Смотри, твоя система основана на событиях. То есть повилось событие newUser - обновилась сцена, событие move - обновилась сцена и тд. делаешь лисенера инициализатора и в зависимости от логики игры инициализируешь бота, не в отдельном процессе все выполняется вместе с сервером. Соднай скрипт, который замускает сервер и инициализирует клиента лисенера, который умеет создавать ботов, все.